# X divs fluid, side by side, with min width and two lines

Tags: jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

I was wondering if someone already had came across a good way of achieving this.

Here is an image to show what i am talking about:

- Don't worry with the sizes, i just threw randomly but to show what i was talking about;
- You will notice on the 1st example, the small squares have the same width as the 3th example;
- On the 2nd example, the squares decreased the width until the window reaches a size that the squares fit again in the default width, and it have 2 squares less than the others.

[image]

Well, i hope it was easy to get it.
I came across a couple solutions but none seems to work seamless.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
    var block_width = 50;
    var margin_right = 5;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        change_width();
    });

    function change_width(){
        var new_width = block_width + ($('#content').width() % (block_width + margin_right)) / Math.floor($('#content').width() / (block_width + margin_right));
        $('.item').width(new_width);
    }
```

CSS

```
#content{
    width:300px; /* set this to how wide you want the container to be */
}

.item{
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:5px; /* is the same as the value in the javascript */
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Call the function `change_width()` whenever you need to recalculate the box sizes. Make sure to have all those divs on the same line since the newline messes up the formatting.

`block_width` refers to the natural block width for each item before they get scaled to fit. and `margin-right` is for if you want to separate your block items.